# Performing operations on sides and diagonals of convex polygon

Tags: combinatorics

Given a convex $n$-gon with $n\geq 4$. We write a positive number on $2n-3$ segments: all sides, and all diagonals from one vertex. If there is a quadrilateral $ABCD$ such that all sides and the diagonal $AC$ have numbers and $BD$ doesn't, we may write the number $(n_{AB}n_{CD}+n_{AD}n_{BC})/n_{AC}$ on $BD$, where $n_X$ denotes the number on side $X$, and erase the number on $AC$. Suppose that after doing this for a while, we're back to having numbers on the original $2n-3$ segments, then prove that the numbers must be the same as the original.

For a quadrilateral ($4$-gon) the statement holds because it is only possible to flip back and forth. For higher $n$ maybe there's an invariant hidden in the configuration.